# Linked-List Code inserts to middle, but don't understand one line

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

The following code inserts a node into the middle of a linked list.  The code works.  My issue is that I don't understand the last line, and no one on here or google seems to have the same problem. Can anyone provide some illumination?

Specifically, does predptr->next = newptr assign the entire new node (newptr), which includes an int n and a pointer to the ancillary struct (predptr) in its entirety, or does it just copy the newptr's pointer to the ancillary pointer's pointer? The first case doesn't seem possible.

If needed, you can assume a list of First -> 9 -> 17 -> 22, where predptr is pointing at 17 and newptr is holding 20, which is what I want to insert before 22.

```
// check for insertion in middle
else if (predptr->next->n > newptr->n)
{
    newptr->next = predptr->next;
    predptr->next = newptr;
}
```

Comment: it copies the pointer

Comment: A(pred)->B(pred_next) => A->new->B

Comment: `next` is just a pointer, so that is what is being copied.

Comment: Many, many thanks! The syntax was driving me nuts, though I knew what was supposed to happen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume all these pointers are of type `Node*` and explain.  Let our `Node` datatype look like:

```
struct Node
{
   int value;
   Node* next;
}
```

Therefore, whenever the datatype Node is initialised, it will occupy 8 bytes (4 for the int, and 4 for the pointer).

A pointer contains as its value, the address of a particular byte in memory. Look at the three statements below:

```
Node a = new Node();
Node* b = &a;
Node* c = b;
```

The first statement initialises `a` somewhere in the memory, say at address location starting `A`. Therefore, `a` will occupy the addresses `A` to `A+7` (8 bytes). The second statement initialises `b` to the address of `a` i.e. the value of `b` will be `A`. The third line initialises `c` to the value of `b`. Therefore, the value contained in `c` will also be `A`.

Now, in your case when you do `preptr->next = newptr`, what you are doing is very similar to Node* c = b. You are copying the value of `newptr` into `next`. The value of newptr is the address of the node to be inserted. Therefore, after doing `preptr->next = newptr`, `next` will be holding the address of the new node which is called `insertion` in the terms of linked list.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful explanation! I cannot believe that I completely forgot that the value of newptr is an address!

Answer (score 0):

The list, before insertion, probably looks something like

```
       +---------+    +--------------------+
... -> | predptr | -> | node after predptr | -> ...
       +---------+    +--------------------+
```

After the first assignment, `newptr->next = predptr->next`, then it looks like this:

```
       +---------+    +--------------------+
... -> | predptr | -> | node after predptr | -> ...
       +---------+    +--------------------+
                      ^
          +--------+  |
          | newptr | -'
          +--------+
```

So after the first assignment, the actual list hasn't changed, you just have two different nodes `next` pointer point to the same node (the node after `predptr` in the list).

What the second assignment (`predptr->next = newptr;`) does is to make `newptr` the node after `predptr`, so the list looks like

```
       +---------+    +--------+    +--------------------+
... -> | predptr | -> | newptr | -> | node after predptr | -> ...
       +---------+    +--------+    +--------------------+
```

When it comes to things like linked lists, I recommend you draw a simple list (like the one above) on *paper* and perform the operations on paper drawing arrows. That way it's easy to actually visualize the lists and what the different operations does.

Comment: You are a God among men. I can't thank you enough for providing such a detailed explanation.